in spring-boot multi-module app, how to set the log level for all modules?
we have a spring-boot maven project.  It has 4 modules, each with their own pom files, and of course the parent pom file.
Currently, without setting it anywhere, the level is DEBUG.
Firstly, I want to figure out how to change this for local dev.
If I add:
logging.level.root: INFO

to one of the modules: mymodule1/src/main/resources/application.yml
It doesn't change. If I add this line to all 4 modules, it seems to work.
Is there a way I only need to change it in one place?  There doesnt seem to be a parent application.yml.
E.g. is there a way to override log level for everything, e.g. command line or env var?
I dont know what version of spring-boot we are using, but in the pom it says:
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>

